# How might a society that was once subjugated by superhumans react to their return?

Tags: society, government, super-powers

The premise is quite simple. Sixty years ago, superhumans were wiped out. The source from which they drew their powers was destroyed and the world moved on. Democracy, the rule of law, human rights etc. flourished and a world not unlike our present one emerged. Now, people are gaining powers once again. Most of them are teenagers, and adults are few and far between. One in one thousand people are likely to manifest abilities. Their power is tremendous and the more time that goes by, the stronger they become. Conventional weapons will soon have no affect on them. Many people are still alive who remember the reign of the superhumans and the impunity with which they ruled, and history books have represented superhumans in the worst possible light (imagine the Nazis).

Does the government/society go on an offensive and try to wipe out as many as they can before their power grows to be too much, or do they try to negotiate and engage these teenagers, who will one day possess the power to level cities?

Comment: Are superhumans inherently bad (like in Brandon Sanderson's "[The Reckoners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reckoners)"), or they can prove themselves to be good?

Comment: Kaaaaaahhhhhnnnnnn!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hi Red Robin, this is an interesting question but is also very much opinion based and hard to answer objectively. I'd recommend narrowing your question down, perhaps by proposing details involved with one of the options you list, and trying a [tag:reality-check] on it to see whether other people also find it reasonable. I've voted to place your question on hold until you get a chance to [edit] it.

Comment: Negotiate with teenagers? Why? Just give them marijuana, and let them be stoners -- munching and playing video games in their mom's basement for a decade. When they emerge, they won't want to use what's left of their powers for evil (and if they do, back into the basement they go). A 40-year-old super-stoner is a threat only to the city's Cheetos and Ice Cream supply.

Answer (score 4):

Some governments might try to destroy them some might try and find allies with them but what I wonder about is the impact of religion.  People have tried to worship all kinds of things and been willing to die in the name of normal people with a bit of charisma.  There is no way there aren't religions worshipping some or all of these superpowered people.

Imagine if the Pope or a crazy street preacher had friends that could burn cities.  No way the government could just wage a war against them if the religion is popular with the masses.  The legal protections for religions could allow them to exist quite comfortably and possibly being worshipped might calm some of these individuals down.  Also depending on what their powers are you might see them setting up moon colonies or something and creating their own governments.

Answer (score 3):

**Negotiations.**

These kids would probably have grown up with the stigma associated with Supers and their tyrannical rule. I think they would separate into 2 groups. Those who are for the current government (and would join an organization and receive aid from them) and those who would do what they want or oppose the government completely (typical villain antics).

The government would probably become aware of this and try to recruit the Pro-Government Supers (PGS). With the cooperation of these PGS, they can research them in hopes to control them and use them to protect the current government.

It leads to the classic Good vs. Evil scenarios depicted in most media. (and definitely governmental shades of gray)

Answer (score 3):

Teach them.

By their nature humans do not want to kill other humans. This was documented in Vietnam for example where soldiers were more likely to try and look busy fir example by discharging their weapon at the trees rather than fire at the enemy.

If you can teach these superhumans respect, boundries and rules you can mitigate a lot of the problems. Additionally you can steer these superhumans to care for things like their family. You can subtly warn for repercussions: "if you go bad we might not be able to stop you, but we could still hurt you. You dont hurt us we dont hurt you". So early on the supers have to already have a ton of life lessons behind their belt to still habe similar values as society when their superpowers mature. You dont want supers to go bad simply because they never experienced a loved one dying before and go into a depression. So constant psychological help is adviced besides things like short-lived pets that can teach them death etc.

That would be the course of a smart government, but when its about a people the reactions will be incredibly varied just like with everything in the world. Just think of this simple list:

- super children will receive death threats every day.
- supers will receive adoration and questions like superstars every day.
- desperate people will make requests of them every day through any known channel. "Can you heal my loved one's? There's people starving can you help them? If you grow old could you stop North Korea?" Etc.
- like celebreties you'll find people seeking to become friends for the potential financial gain, favoritism or other social advantages of befriending a super.
- some people will seek to exploit supers, trying to manipulate them to do anything that the exploiter may want. Some might simply think it is a necessary evil to achieve a better world and some will simply want to control the power of a super for their own power and enrichment.
- cults will form seeking to indirectly gain favor.
- some individuals or groups will actively try to kill supers before they become a threat.
- nations will do all of the above but on larger scales. From recruiting supers in various ways to building weapons and plans to control or kill any runaway super. For example by making every super child get a sickness early on and during the operation a kill device is implanted just in case.

Answer (score 2):

It entirely depends on two factors:

1. how bad the superhumans were

and, possibly far more importantly

2. how much worse legend has made them.

If the society has a founding mythology in which the rules of the superhumans makes Nazi Europe look like a spa resort then they'll have no choice but to react violently to any possibility of their return. If not from policy then due to public pressure. If their perspective is more moderate then so will their reaction be, down too doing nothing whatsoever if they've completely forgotten the horrors of the past.

Their reaction may also be moderated by the place of violence in modern society, if they're as trigger happy as we are these days it looks bad for the kiddies but if they've taken a sharp turn toward pacifism after they freed themselves from subjugation then it will be a very different proposition.

Comment: In terms of the devastation and widespread disruption they caused, the history books are largely accurate. Perhaps some of their virtues were left out, including the fact that many superhumans fought against the supremacy of their fellows, but the potential for abuse of superhuman powers is likely to be at the forefront of everyone's mind. As for violence...almost every government in this 'world' has been waiting for the other shoe to drop, so there is a preparedness on the part of some groups to engage in immediate and total eradication of the threat if it reappears.

Comment: @RedRobin I would expect at least a modicum of violence then, registration, segregation, detention and coercion in the case of those who won't co-operate. Sounds like they're on something of a cold war footing sans the superhumans, not doing anything but ready to go at a moment's notice, maintaining that requires a real kill or be killed mentality, they'll slaughter them out of hand and probably their families too just in case.

Answer (score 2):

You've mentioned an escalation in power but your time frame is too tight for this build up to be occurring across generations.  The stronger powers are not the product of having powered parents, but instead appear to be escalating within a single generation.

So killing off the currently empowered is not going to keep future, even stronger, powers from emerging.  It is only a matter of time before a single world-dominating power arrives which will defeat any human resistance with overwhelming completeness.

So don't start a war you can't win.  The only winning move for the powerless is to negotiate for peaceful coexistence while your scientists frantically search for the source of the new powers.  Once you find the power source, more options may become available,

but for right now...

don't get them angry... you won't like them when they get angry!

Answer (score -1):

There will be an active search to find the new source(s) of the new superhumans' powers.  When the superhumans get to be dangerous enough, the new source(s) will either be destroyed, or captured and defended by superhumans.

Comment: This answer does not address the question.

Comment: @EDL -- This answer explains how the society would react to the new superhumans -- by eventually trying to destroy the new source(s) of the superhumans' power.